# I am not able to update plugins. Its asking FTP details. My website is on AWS

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services

When I am trying to update plugins and themes in my website I am getting an issue:

```
To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.
```

Comment: If you are the web admin verify the permissions of the files/directories. the owner and group suppose to be www-data:www-data.

Comment: If you have the option, get WP CLI (https://wp-cli.org) and update from the command line; it's far more secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to modify or define `FS_METHOD` variable in your Wordpress configuration file

```php
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Add this line in your wordpress config.php file

Comment: Awesome! You are the man.
I spent many hours to find the solution of this issue.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Please check your permissions for the wordpress folder on your server. I think you have wrong permissions.